# Why do my p elements not center align-center with boostrap flexbox properties?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

This is the code I'm concerned with:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" id="footer">
      <div>Copyright 2019<span>&#169;</span></div>
      <div>Back to Top</div>
      <!-- <p>Copyright 2019<span>&#169;</span></p>
      <p>Back to Top</p> -->
    </div>
```

If you comment out the divs and try it out with the p tags, the align-items center class does not work. Why does the class work with the div's but not the p elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove margins for `<p>`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/9Lwstm5r/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `p tag` has `margin-bottom` of `1rem;`  Adding `mb-0` to the p tag might solve your problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" id="footer">
  <p class="mb-0">Copyright 2019<span>&#169;</span></p>
  <p class="mb-0">Back to Top</p>
</div>
```